# How to send message in peer to peer messaging when other user is offline?

Tags: networking

I have a server and many clients. Each client registers to server when first time it connects to server. At instant of time server maintains a list of usernames and their ip addresses and their public ports of users(clients) who are online.

A user X may ask server for this list and can directly contact to another user Y using ip and port to corresponding Y and start messaging.The user X keeps username of user Y in its contact.

After sometime user X again wants to contact the user Y in its list but find user Y is now offline (list of online users does not contains X's name), now how will user X contact to user Y ?

Comment: not getting into programming, but I would sort it the same way phone communications work. User called not answering? He gets a "whoever called you".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would temporarily store the message that X sent to Y in the server, and once user Y is back online, the server will push the message to Y himself (letting Y know in some way, that the message originated from X)

Comment: What if user Y suddenly leaves the chat and closes application?

Comment: You mean that Y is closed suddenly? You should create a close routine that will send a notification to the server that it is being closed, so that the server can update its tables accordingly. Also, are you using TCP or UDP? If using TCP, you can know that the packet never arrived at Y, and then resend the packet to the server (and possibly even notify the server that X is not responding)